# laravel6 - Why/How default middlewares work without handle method?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am now learning Laravel and have a basic question regarding how middleware works.
Per documentation, in order to make middleware work, we need handle method. However, there's a couple of default middlewares with no handle method. One example is Middleware/Authenticate.php from laravel/ui. I don't see any handle method in its file but the authentication surely works when we call middleware('auth').
Can anyone please enlighten me on why/how default middlewares work without handle method?

Thank you,

Comment: There are three kind of middleware, Global, Group and Route middleware. Read about it on laravel doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That middleware class extends `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate` most likely, which has a `handle` method.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer makes perfect sense.